# World transfer button disappeared after login, how to carry on?

Tags: lord-of-the-rings-online

Today when I started LOTRO I received a patch. After the log in I discovered two buttons instead of one. The first is 'Play' and the second is 'Transfer'. I'm aware of the [world transfer event](https://www.lotro.com/en/game/articles/world-transfers) and wanted to prepare my characters for the transfer.
So I clicked the 'Play' button, prepared the characters and exited the game.
I restarted LOTRO, logged in and found the Transfer button missing!

**Is there anything I can do to make the transfer?** Did I missed my chance?

**UPDATE**
24 hours later, the button magically reappeared.
However, I still cannot transfer my characters since the worlds i can transfer **from** are the same as the new servers! **Am I messing up here?**

**Another update**
48 hours after asking the question: Button is missing again. :(
72 hours after asking the question: Button is still missing.

**yet another update**
1 week later: Got an update, button is back again, however... The world with my main characters is not listed as a potential world to transfer from. Also, the target worlds are the same as origin.  So now it is basically the same as a week ago but now they switch the server list :(.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Here](https://www.lotro.com/forums/showthread.php?575685-World-Transfer-Status-Update-8-26-2015&p=7431991#post7431991) is a post on the official forums with an update on the world transfers. Hopefully this explains what you've been seeing.

Comment: That really clarify a lot. It also states that it will take a while before everything will be ready (perhaps months).

Answer (score 0):

A couple of days ago, they removed transfer with no ETA, because something was not working. Check the Lord of the Rings Online Twitter account.

Comment: Could you provide a source? Perhaps a link to the twitter announcement?

Comment: I did not receive any software update. And as mister Timelord is saying, do you have any source?